# Enumerate label style A.#number

Tags: enumerate

I want to make my enumerate list to do the following:

Everly enumerates label starts if a letter A.#number where the number is adjusted automatically by the counter.

For example,

A.1   Text

A.2    Text

A.3   Text

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  You could use `\usepackage{enumitem}` with `\begin{enumerate}[label={\Alph*\theenumi }]`. [Related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/379919/124842)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have many lists like this you can define a new list environment: `Aenumerate`, after you've added this code to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{Aenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[Aenumerate]{label=A.\arabic*}
```

Otherwise, simply load `enumitem` and use this code in the body of your document:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=A.\arabic*]
\item ...
   ⋮
\end{enumerate}
```